# MVVM Property does not updates

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have strange problem with property updating

My model looks like

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TestSome.DataType;
using TestSome.MessageInfrastructure;
using TestSome.WorkingWithNode;

namespace TestSome.Model
{
    class CentralModel
    {
        private BalanceTest someTest;
        public BalanceTest SomeTest
        {
            get { return someTest; }
            set { someTest = value; }
        }
        public void ListenBalance()
        {
            SocketHandler.Socket.Handle.Add("balance", (m) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    BalanceTest bt = m.Message.Json.GetFirstArgAs<BalanceTest>();
                    SomeTest = bt;
                    Messenger.Default.Send(new BalanceCommunicator { TestBalance = bt }, "Token");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel looks like

```
public class BalanceViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private BalanceTest some;
    public BalanceTest Some
    {
        get { return some; }
        set { some = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Some"); }
    }
    private CentralModel CM;
    public BalanceViewModel()
        {
            try
            {
                CM = new CentralModel();
                CM.ListenBalance();
                Some = CM.SomeTest;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

And Xaml looks like

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestSome.Views.BalanceView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Test="clr-namespace:TestSome.Model"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Test:CentralModel x:Key="CentralMode"></Test:CentralModel>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Expander ExpandDirection="Right">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

        <Label Content="{Binding SomeTest.Balance,Source={StaticResource CentralMode},Mode=TwoWay}"></Label>
</StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

Why it does not updates?

Comment: Have you initialized DataContext?

Comment: public BalanceView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new BalanceViewModel();
        }

Comment: Please don't arbitrarily italicize every bit of text. It's useless.

Comment: You don't appear to be binding to the ViewModel's `Some` property.  Also, the `Some` property is only set during the `BalanceViewModel` constructor.  Your code doesn't show where the value is being changed.

Comment: SocketHandler.Socket.Handle.Add get's new values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you implement an `event` in your `CentralModel` class and a handler in your `BalanceViewModel`, in order to communicate the new data upwards.

In the CentralModel class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Raised when a new balance is received.
/// </summary>
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> NewBalanceEvent;

public void ListenBalance()
{
    SocketHandler.Socket.Handle.Add("balance", (m) =>
    {
        try
        {
            BalanceTest bt = m.Message.Json.GetFirstArgAs<BalanceTest>();
            SomeTest = bt;
            Messenger.Default.Send(new BalanceCommunicator { TestBalance = bt }, "Token");

            // Raise the event
            EventHandler<EventArgs> RaiseNewBalanceEvent = NewBalanceEvent;
            if (null != RaiseNewBalanceEvent)
            {
                RaiseNewBalanceEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    });
}
```

And in your BalanceViewModel class hook the event:

```
private void NewBalanceEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // This will trigger the property changed event.
    Some = CM.SomeTest;
}

public BalanceViewModel()
{
    try
    {
        CM = new CentralModel();
        CM.ListenBalance();
        Some = CM.SomeTest;

        // Attach to the NewBalance event
        // Note: you should detatch it again (with -=) when you've finished with it.
        CM.NewBalanceEvent += NewBalanceEventHandler;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now, whenever the Lambda in the `SocketHandler.Socket.Handle.Add` gets called, the `CentralModel` raises the `NewBalanceEvent`, which in turn (via the framework) calls the `BalanceViewModel`'s event handler delegate and the `Some` property gets updated.

**EDIT**

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29252322/3581917), provided by [fix-likes-coding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633957/fix-likes-coding) is correct: you need to bind to the correct property in the View.

Answer (score 0):

You're not raising `RaisePropertyChanged("SomeTest")` on your SomeTest property. Why would it work? :)

Comment: `SomeTest` is the model

Comment: I think it wouldn't help. I implemented NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeTest"); Nothing happens.

Comment: what i like doing is adding every section of a binding as binding of a textblock to see at which point a binding goes wrong. otherwise you can also configure your debugger to show binding errors in output

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to `Some` of your BalanceViewModel and not to the CentralModel

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Some.Balance,Mode=TwoWay}"></Label>
```

Comment: 1. Does it displays correctly the start value? 2. You never change the value. 3. did you put breakpoints to check whats going on?

Comment: I think that you are right, that it's raise only when initializing. Can you advise how to raise updates of this property every time? Use timer or...? Thanks.
1.Start value it display correctly
2. it's changing but ui doesn't updates.
3/ yes